# How to print a variable in SQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, ubuntu

```
CREATE DATABASE loan_data;
USE loan_data;
    
CREATE TABLE loan_user (
    id long,
    amount long
    );
    
INSERT INTO loan_user(id, amount)
values (1,7000), (2,7000), (3,5000);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE loan_check()
BEGIN
DECLARE a int;  
select a = count(amount) from loan_user where amount=7000;
print a;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
CALL loan_check();

DROP DATABASE loan_data;
```

I want to print the `a` variable in the above code. But the code returns

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a;
END' at line 5
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an OUT variable

> ```
> CREATE TABLE loan_user (
>     id long,
>     amount long
>     );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO loan_user(id, amount)
> values (1,7000), (2,7000), (3,5000);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE loan_check(OUT _answer BIGINT)
> BEGIN
> DECLARE a int;  
> select  count(amount) into a from loan_user where amount=7000;
> SET _answer =  a;
> END
> ```

> ```
> SET @answer := 0;
> CALL loan_check(@answer);
> SELECT IF(@answer = 2, 'yes',@answer)as answer
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> | answer |
> | :----- |
> | yes    |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=feb06974a2cee340430a3c8ebbe5a16c)**

Or simply don_'t use INTO  or :=

> ```
> CREATE TABLE loan_user (
>     id long,
>     amount long
>     );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO loan_user(id, amount)
> values (1,7000), (2,7000), (3,5000);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE loan_check()
> BEGIN
> DECLARE a int;  
> select  count(amount)  from loan_user where amount=7000;
>
> END
> ```

> ```
> CALL loan_check();
> ```

> ```
> | count(amount) |
> | ------------: |
> |             2 |
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE loan_check2(_inc int)
> BEGIN
> DECLARE a int;  
> select  IF(count(amount) = 2 , 'yes',COUNT(amount)) as answer from loan_user where amount=_inc;
>
> END
> ```

> ```
> CALL loan_check2(7000);
> ```
>
> ```
> | answer |
> | :----- |
> | yes    |
>
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1427476cf64d73acca75ede7b21e8cc7)*

Comment: Thank you. This works. How do I extend it to, ```If (answer==2) print 'yes'```?

Comment: i added a solution forboth versions

Comment: Why is the 'select' command being used to print? there is no 'print' command in sql? Literature suggests there is, but I am not able to run it.

Comment: no there exit no print comand in sql, to get a result set you nned a SELECT

Answer (score 0):

If it's just yo debug your stored procedure, PRINT is not a MySQL stored procedure command, you should use something similar to this:

```
 SQL  CREATE PROCEDURE demo_a()
    - BEGIN
    - DECLARE a int;
    - SELECT SUM(1+2) into @a;
    - SELECT @a;
    - END ||

 SQL  delimiter ;

 SQL  call demo_a();
+----+
| @a |
+----+
|  3 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.0014 sec)
```

Now it you want to get that value as an output of your stored procedure, you should use an OUT variable as you have been advised too.

Comment: the second select isn't needed see my answer